# How to execute the same PHP script from C several times on different thread?

Tags: php, c, multithreading

I'm trying to make a push notification server that send all the pending notification to Apple. I use a PHP script to retrieve all 'pending' notifications from database, mark them as 'sending' in the database and does send them to Apple.

What I want to do is :

- Execute this script every second
- Do not wait until the previous script finishes, to call this script again (sometime when there is > 2000 pending notifications, one script can take up to 10-20s to send them. But, I don't want to block the sending of new 'pending' notification that could have come meanwhile, thats why I don't want to wait until the previous script is finished)

Only way to do that is I guess using thread. As i'm not used to work with thread in PHP, I created a C program like that :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void *start_instance(void *arg)
{
    printf("Start new php script..\n");
    system("php -f send_pending_push_notif.php");


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(1) {
        pthread_t thrd;


        if(pthread_create(&thrd, NULL, start_instance, NULL) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create thread\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        sleep(1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

The problem is that output is like so (let's say it takes 1 sec to send 3 notifs)

```
[c] Start new php script..
[php] script no 2342 // (random value to trace which php script sent the notif) 
[php] sending notif 2342:0 
[php] sending notif 2342:1 
[php] sending notif 2342:2 
[c] Start new php script.. 
[php] sending notif 2342:3
[php] sending notif 2342:4
[php] end of sending script ! 
[php] script no 6544 
[php] sending notif 6544:0 
[php] sending notif 6544:1 
[php] sending notif 6544:2 
[c] Start new php script.. 
[php] sending notif 6544:3
[php] sending notif 6544:4
```

So the thread does launch after 1 sec but it looks like PHP CLI program "queue" the scripts to execute if one have not finished yet.
I would like an output like that :

```
[c] Start new php script..
[php] script no 2342 // (random value to trace which php script sent the notif) 
[php] sending notif 2342:0 
[php] sending notif 2342:1 
[php] sending notif 2342:2 
[c] Start new php script.. 
[php] script no 6544 
[php] sending notif 2342:3
[php] sending notif 6544:0 
[php] sending notif 2342:4
[php] sending notif 6544:1 
[php] end of 2342 script ! 
[php] sending notif 6544:2 
[php] sending notif 6544:3
[php] sending notif 6544:4
```

PS : Don't hesitate to tell me if my push notification server logic is over complicated, or if you would know any easier way to achieve this (cron is every minute only, and i'm not even sure it would open PHP scripts parrallely ..)

Comment: You would not be needing to execute a script every second though. how about more processing for a single cron call every minute?

Comment: If I execute my script every minute, people on my app will have their notification one minute later. As my app includes messaging service it needs to be sent as fast as possible

Comment: So if someone messages someone else, it goes to  your server first. There you could just hit Apple API to make it send a push to a particular device. You can let Apple handle the push notification for you with you only sending API request to Apple to do so when  a user sends message to another user.

Comment: I have never been into this field so can't say much but this link should help. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/

Comment: And I don’t want my user to wait until Apple responds to get their HTTP request response, that’s why my user “queue” new notifications in the database and every second I want this script (that is not executed on my Apache machines, but on a dedicated machine) to dequeue these new notifications from the database and send them to Apple

Comment: Ok.. you mean sending notification request to Apple without waiting for their response ? Problem with this solution is that I will never get Apple response error packet in case it happens (Apple return a error packet if device ID is corrupted)

Comment: Hmm.. In that case you will have to look at how messaging apps are implemented for iPhones. They sure might have handled the error packet problem.  Also with your approach, you will have to make sure the machines could handle the load to check for every second since many users could be messaging at once.

Comment: The interesting advantage of creating a dedicated push notification server is that I can queue pending notifications in the database and control the load charge of the machine by setting a poll limit for each script ( my script has a poll limit from my database of 1000 notifications, if there are more pending within 1 second, it will be for the next script, one second later)

Comment: But maybe I omitted another much more simple way to do that....

Comment: In that case, you also need to mark those entries in the database, else, other threads could read the same entries, ultimately duplicating push notifications. I am sure you would already be handling this.

Comment: Of course, as they are retrieved by one script they are marked as « sending », and next scripts take only « pending » notifications:) but I still can’t manage to execute several thread parallely with this C program:/

Comment: The best I can help you with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978617/parallel-threads-in-c

Comment: I ll read this thanks for your answers :)